# How do I get my Clash of Clans account back?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I did the new update and I didn't have it backed up so I had to uninstall the game. I lost my account. How can I get it back?

Answer (score 0):

If you were signed in to a social media service, sign back in. Otherwise, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you got a new phone and you have your same Apple id or didn't get a new phone but you have the same Apple id then you go to updates purchased and all your apps should be there I mean if you have a iPhone

Answer (score 0):

Install the app and go to Settings -> Help. Click on the Contact us and it will send some game info. If you are signed into your account they can help.

I lost my city and it took about a month for them to respond but eventually I got it back. I had months of work into it and some gem purchases so I didn't want to lose it all. If you can rebuild what you had in a month do that, they are not quick to get back to you.